# Creating 26 alphabet letter buttons with the for loop and String.fromCharCode()

Tags: javascript, button, for-loop, alphabet

here is some HTML Code as example:

```
<button onclick="setLetter('A');">A</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('B');">B</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('C');">C</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('D');">D</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('E');">E</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('F');">F</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('G');">G</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('H');">H</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('I');">I</button>
<button onclick="setLetter('J');">J</button>
...
...

<div id="name"></div>
```

here the javascript part:

```
function setLetter(letter) {
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML + letter;
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but has a lot of redundancy, which I want to remove basicly by using the for loop and the method `String.fromCharCode()`. I just cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: How is one line of javascript "a lot of redundancy"?

Comment: Oh im sorry I ment the HTML Code with the 26 buttons not the jscript

Comment: I think 26 x online `onclick="setLetter('letter')"` is a lot of redundancy. Imagine there are 80.000 chinese characters.

Comment: You could look at that from the other side and think that coding this up will also introduce a lag (though obviously very slight)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj35L9w2/3/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttonsHolder"></div>
<div id="name"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function( windowLoadE ) {
    var p, letter, button, holder;
    holder = document.getElementById( "buttonsHolder" );
    for ( var i = 65; i <= 90; i++ ) {
        if ( i == 65 || i == 75 || i == 84 ) {
            p = document.createElement( "p" );
        }
        letter = String.fromCharCode( i );
        button = document.createElement( "button" );
        button.innerHTML = letter;
        button.setAttribute( "data-letter", letter );
        button.onclick = function( e ) { setLetter( this.getAttribute( "data-letter" ) ); };
        p.appendChild( button );
        if ( i == 74 || i == 83 || i == 90 ) {
            holder.appendChild( p );
        }
    }
} );
function setLetter( letter ) {
    var div = document.getElementById( "name" );
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + letter;
}
```

This solution like @Arvind's, but I think better use `attribute` of html tag and set `onclick` with `function`s.

```js
window.addEventListener( "load", function( windowLoadE ) {
    var p, letter, button, holder;
    holder = document.getElementById( "buttonsHolder" );
    for ( var i = 65; i <= 90; i++ ) {
        if ( i == 65 || i == 75 || i == 84 ) {
            p = document.createElement( "p" );
        }
        letter = String.fromCharCode( i );
        button = document.createElement( "button" );
        button.innerHTML = letter;
        button.setAttribute( "data-letter", letter );
        button.onclick = function( e ) { setLetter( this.getAttribute( "data-letter" ) ); };
        p.appendChild( button );
        if ( i == 74 || i == 83 || i == 90 ) {
            holder.appendChild( p );
        }
    }
} );
function setLetter( letter ) {
    var div = document.getElementById( "name" );
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + letter;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonsHolder"></div>
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: when I test the code in my own HTML and jscript the buttons are not shown but when i test it on jsfiddle it works..why is that? I mean when i put the javascript code into the html it works but when i do it in seperate file the buttons wont show up

Comment: @CuttingTheAces it cause you add this script in `head` section and when it initializes `document.body` doesn't exist. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Lj35L9w2/1/

Comment: ok nice it works now. what do i need to change to get it so the buttons will be above the letters not other way around?

Comment: @CuttingTheAces I'm update answer. You just need to add some element before `name` div and add buttons to this element instead `document.body`.

Comment: ok good. one last thing how do i make a <p>/paragraph in javascript i want the buttons to be in 3 rows like: ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRS TUVWXYZ but among eachother not side by side. like on the keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var html = '';
var c;
for (var i = 65; 90 >= i; i++) {// A-65, Z-90
  c = String.fromCharCode(i);
  html += '<button onclick="setLetter(\'' + c + '\');">' + c + '</button>';
}
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = html;

var setLetter = function(x) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += x;
};
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="name"></div>
```

Comment: when I test the code in my own HTML and jscript the buttons are not shown but when i test it on jsfiddle it works..why is that? I mean when i put the javascript code into the html it works but when i do it in seperate file the buttons wont show up